# OnTouchListener у Layout

Tags: android, android-sdk, разметка, ontouchlistener

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется два Layout:

A - RelativeLayout.
B - LinearLayout.

Вот пример разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/menuParentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        >

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

На  `Layout` **A** я установил слушатель OnTouchListener. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на область `Layout` **B** или на его потомков, слушатель не срабатывал, а при касании за границей Layout **A** срабатывал.

При нажатии на Spinner слушатель Layout **A** не срабатывает, т.к. на нем (спиннере) есть свой родной слушатель, однако у View его нет. Установить на него слушатель не вариант. Что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте `OnTouchListener` для `Layout B` и в нём устанавливайте значение булевой переменной, а в `OnTouchListener` для `Layout A` проверяйте значение этой переменной. Например, так:

```
boolean ChildTouched = false;
RelativeLayout ParentLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuParentLayout);
ParentLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (ChildTouched) {
            ChildTouched = false;
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("Touch parent activity");
        return true;
    }
});

LinearLayout ChildLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.menuLayout);
ChildLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Touch child activity");
        ChildTouched = true;
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало